# Tutorial on Ethereum wallet, create your token: strange behaviour

Tags: mist, contract-debugging, tokens

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/) using ethereum-wallet (mist) 0.5.0.

I'm running geth on a custom network launched as:

```
geth --datadir ~/ethprivatechain/testing/01/ --networkid 42371325 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --ipcpath /home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc  console
```

I've created three addresses, let's call them : base, Acc2 and Acc3.

I've created two wallet contracts: one for base, one for Acc2.

I've created a token contract as described in the tutorial, using base as the source of ether - the base had 10000 units of these tokens.

I sent 50 of these tokens from base to Acc3.
(I would expect now to have base with 9950 tokens and Acc3 with 50)

What I have: base with 50 tokens, 9950 disappeared and nowhere to be found, Acc3 with 50 tokens.

Is it a bug of the contract found [here](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/?gist=21935dc37c5bfbe92e5a)?